# Rewrite url to hide ?p=

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, webserver

I am new to the .htaccess file and I have a site. The URLs look like https://example.com/content/main.php?p=contact .
I want the URLs to look like https://example.com/content/contact but act the same, because I use the 'p' parameter in the main.php file to include the matching html files. All other html files are in a seperate folder to avoid url conflicts.

I tried

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^content/([^/]+)$ content/main.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^content/([^/]+)/$ content/main.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```

but when I type
https://example.com/content/contact
it says page not found.
I have no files or directories that are named 'contact' and the main.php file finds the files i want it to include.

I also tried

```
RewriteBase content/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /main\.php\?p=.+ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [L,R]
```

from another question here, but it gives me an error (Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request).

And I also have `RewriteEngine On` in the .htaccess file.
And the .htaccess file is in the root directory (https://example.com/.htaccess)

Could there be some settings that prevent the .htaccess file from rewritung thr url?
Or is there an other way than doing it with the .htaccess file?
I also have this "" in second code block but not in the first one. Does it have impact on the functionality?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The code in your first block looks "OK" (albeit too verbose). (Assuming `/content/terme` does not itself map to a file or directory?!) Have you confirmed that `main.php` is not actually receiving the request? (Is the "page not found" response generated by `main.php` perhaps?)

Comment: What "error" did the 2nd code block result in? (All that should do is redirect requests for `/main.php?p=<something>` to `/main.php` - not what you want to do, but neither should that be an "error".)

Comment: @MrWhite there is no directory or file called like this. Also, all files included in main.php are found. https://example.com/content/main.php?p=terme works, https://example.com/content/terme not